# Background image not scaling the entire section of the body of the page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not able to set the background image in the MVC page to full screen. The output on my screen is as follows

[image]

Not sure what the problem is. I have set the background image of the body tag to cover in the app.css file. As you can see in the screenshot, the image is behind the grid and only visible at the top. There is blank space at the bottom of the screen,

My css is as follows

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-top: none;
    background-image: url('../Images/iNeed__waterfall_BG.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

**Layout page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/angular.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jszip.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>

</head>
<body >

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/NGSR-logo.jpg" /> </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>


                        <li class="dropdown hideli">
                            @*<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">*@
                                <select class="form-control">
                                    <option><a href="#">ALL</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">DE</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">GB</a></option>
                                    <option><a href="#">FR</a></option>
                                </select>
                                <p>Country</p>
                            @*</a>*@
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div>

        @RenderBody()
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
html,body {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: cover;         /* Generic*/
}
```

or :

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: I tried both. The first is not liked by css3. The second one shows me the samething as in the screen shot

Comment: The another thing that  I have noticed is that if I comment the grid which is in the index.html, the image disappears. Normally only the image is expected. I failed to understand what is happening. There is no reference to the image in the index.html.

Comment: do you set for html tag?

Comment: Yes. I have put the html tag